# Virtual machine hosting with priority

Tags: virtual-machines

The simplified problem:

I have 3 servers on which I want to host virtual machines. Some VMs are more important than others.

Should I keep the important ones on a "high priority" server and the others on the other two servers?
Or should I make servers with both very important and less important machines?

What is the best practice here and why?

Answer (score 0):

better organize HA between two servers and keeps the third as slave.

Answer (score 0):

I daresay that there is no real "best practice" for this.

However, if you can structure your virtual machines into a "high SLA host" and a "low SLA host" or similar, it is much easier to manage in the long run.

**Amazon Web Services** does something *like* this, Example: all `t1.micro` instances run on one host, all `c1.xlarge` instances run on one host, etc.